# case and white space insensitive hashing function

Tags: hash

I am looking for a hashing function that is case insensitive and ignores white spaces as well.

for example:

the hash value generated for `this is a hash` and `ThisIsAHash` will be exactly the same.

does any such hash function exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hash Functions are how we make them. For example:

First, for all strings ->

Step1. Lowercase them (or Uppercase them)
Step2. Strip all Whitespaces.

By now, both strings would map to: thisisahash

Step3. Now, apply any Hash function to it: crc32, java's polynomial or whatever...

Given a string, you can always now do a lookup and see if other Strings are hashed to the same key.

Note that hash functions are one-way. So doing Step1 and Step2 don't count against valid hash methods.

Comment: yes that i have thought of. but is there no direct method of doing it at all?

Comment: Even the hash function which is a blackbox, someone has to code it, right? :)